# emacs newbie question - how to search within a region

Tags: search, emacs

If I select a region of text, is there a way to use isearch (or some other search command) that will allow me to only search within the region? I was hoping to use this to technique inside a macro.

This might be obvious, but I did a quick search and couldn't find a way.

Comment: Any time you ask a question on emacs, be prepared for the answer, "just use vi".  ;-)

Comment: @dave
and vice versa

Comment: @Dave - Rodger that. I've been using vi for 5 years, and decided to give emacs a try. I've only been using it for a week, but I have to say, I'm liking it a lot so far...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use this combination of commands:

```
M-x narrow-to-region
C-s SOMETEXT
M-x widen
```

Though, that's kind of burdensome, here's a new command that does the above for you automatically.

```
(defun isearch-forward-region-cleanup ()
  "turn off variable, widen"
  (if isearch-forward-region
      (widen))
  (setq isearch-forward-region nil))

(defvar isearch-forward-region nil
  "variable used to indicate we're in region search")

(add-hook 'isearch-mode-end-hook 'isearch-forward-region-cleanup)

(defun isearch-forward-region (&optional regexp-p no-recursive-edit)
  "Do an isearch-forward, but narrow to region first."
  (interactive "P\np")
  (narrow-to-region (point) (mark))
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (setq isearch-forward-region t)
  (isearch-mode t (not (null regexp-p)) nil (not no-recursive-edit)))
```

Now just do <kbd>M-x isearch-forward-region RET SOMETEXT</kbd>, or bind it to a key binding of your preference like:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-S-s") 'isearch-forward-region)
```

Comment: Thanks, Trey, this opens a whole new set of possibilities ;-)

Comment: Never knew about narrow and widen. How I love you, emacs.

Comment: there should be something like `isearch-region` or `look-region` that could be invoked from `M-x` without narrowing and then widening back

Answer (score 21):

As Trey Jackson said, you can use `narrow-to-region` and `widen`. I'll chip in for the keyboard shortcuts. Note that they are disabled by default, and emacs will interactively prompt to "undisable" them on the first use.

```
C-x n n
C-s sometext
C-x n w
```

Comment: Thanks much, SO comes thru yet again.

Comment: I had a (global-set-key "\C-xn" 'other-window) in my .emacs for at least 10 years, had no idea it shadowed those.  Thanks.